# How to find the line which the run-time error occurred - visual c++

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, vector, runtime-error

I am write win32 program, using Visual c++ 2010, I have about 6,000 lines of code in my program. almost all the run time errors, are `vector subscript out of range`, so in the error message I got the number of line in the vector file, as this:

[image]

is there any way to know the line in my *.cpp code the error occurred ?

Comment: As the dialog box says.... "Press Retry to debug the application" !!!

Comment: no ! whene I press Retry it get to the vector file. and show me these lines: `#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
  if (size() <= _Pos)
   { // report error
   _DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range");
   _SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
   }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the error happens look in the debugger stack window. It shows the sequence of calls that led to the error. A few layers up in that window will be your code. Double-click on that line and it will display your source code that made the call.

Comment: I see only the output window, not the debugger stack window. How do I show it?

Answer (score 1):

press alt+7 will show the call stack window.