# How to debug runtime errors in Visual Studio Code (determine what line caused the error)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2022

programming newbie here. This is probably a very basic question and perhaps I am simply misunderstanding how runtime errors work, so thanks for bearing with me.

When I run a C++ program with the Local Windows Debugger in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022, an error message pops up:

[Error message example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7edX.png)

However, as far as I can tell, this error message provides no help in determining what line of code in my cpp file actually caused this error. Pressing "Retry" only unhelpfully brings up the actual class file from which the exception was thrown:

[Example after clicking "Retry"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qSNA.png)

This makes it clear what type of error is occurring but not what line of my program the error stems from. Is there any way native to Visual Studio that I can simply determine what line of my program caused a runtime error? I've looked all over the internet but I still can't seem to find a straightforward answer. [This question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342483/how-to-find-the-line-which-the-run-time-error-occurred-visual-c?newreg=12e8f985389146bf839c0c27688a17f8)  appears to ask the same question, however it is outdated as the Call Stack feature was apparently removed.

Comment: The Call Stack has not been removed.  If it was, there would be complaints by thousands of programmers, if not millions.  Maybe a better question would be "where is the call stack window?" or "how do you bring up the call stack in Visual Studio 2022", instead of assuming it's gone?

Comment: In the main menu in Visual Studio: `Debug->Windows->Call Stack` or the default shortcut of `Ctrl+Alt+C`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Forgive me; I read a Microsoft article which I suppose I misinterpreted as saying the call stack had been removed. "Maybe a better question would be "where is the call stack window?" or "how do you bring up the call stack in Visual Studio 2022"' -- Perhaps I would have asked one of these questions if I knew the call stack's functionality and importance, but as a beginner, I did not, and thus simply assumed it was removed.

Comment: Just to let you know, the call stack is one of, if not the most important pieces of a debugging environment, Visual Studio, gdb, or any other debugger for other compilers and languages you can imagine.  Without it, a debugger is almost useless except for tracing and stepping.   So if MS actually did remove the call stack, the programming community would want MS to have their heads examined.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)